# How does Python decide what to change and when to change it?

Tags: python

Code:

```
a = "1"
b = "2"
c = "3"
d = "4"
e = "5"
f = "6"
g = "7"
h = "8"
i = "9"
attempts = 2
while attempts > 0:
    board = f'| {a} | {b} | {c} |\n| {d} | {e} | {f} |\n| {g} | {h} | {i} |'
    a = "x"
    attempts -= 1
    print(attempts)
    print(board)
```

Output:

```
1
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
0
| x | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
```

Why doesn't `board` change immediately unlike `attempts`?
Also, if I leave `board` outside of the while loop like so:

```
a = "1"
b = "2"
c = "3"
d = "4"
e = "5"
f = "6"
g = "7"
h = "8"
i = "9"
attempts = 2
board = f'| {a} | {b} | {c} |\n| {d} | {e} | {f} |\n| {g} | {h} | {i} |'
while attempts > 0:
    a = "x"
    attempts -= 1
    print(attempts)
    print(board)
```

The output becomes:

```
1
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
0
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
```

Why doesn't `board`change at all while `attempts` changes perfectly fine?

Comment: Why do you expect board to change?

Comment: An f-string substitutes the variable when you assign it, not when it's printed.

Comment: You are not changing the value of ```board``` once, it is defined, it is not even touched by python, except when you print it

Comment: So reassigning `a` doesn't change `board`

Comment: Think of it as just a shortcut for calling the `str.format()` method.

Comment: It's just like when you do `a = b + c`. If you then do change `b`, it won't change the vvalue of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason is that you are not really updating board, in the same iteration after you change the variable `a`, which doesnt update `board` automatically. You should change board right after you change the variable `a`.

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for.

```
a = "1"
b = "2"
c = "3"
d = "4"
e = "5"
f = "6"
g = "7"
h = "8"
i = "9"
attempts = 2
board = f'| {a} | {b} | {c} |\n| {d} | {e} | {f} |\n| {g} | {h} | {i} |'
print(attemps)
print(board)

while attempts > 0:   
    a = "x"
    board = f'| {a} | {b} | {c} |\n| {d} | {e} | {f} |\n| {g} | {h} | {i} |'
    attempts -= 1
    print(attempts)
    print(board)
```